# rxgraph with multiple namespace

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I visualize more than one node (namespace) with rxgraph? For example:

```
rxgraph --nodens={\node1 \node2 \node3}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12665/rxgraph-with-multiple-namespace/) by [tiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1659/tiko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt it can do a list of namespaces, but you can run it in the root namespace (`/`). Then it should see everything.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-01-18**:
joq is correct, the feature requested is not implemented, unless I implemented it by accident. If you really need this feature, the source is there for hacking.